# Books/papers on Insurance Derivatives?

Tags: derivatives, insurance

I am looking to learn more about insurance-linked securities. I work for an insurance company and am interested in catastrophe risks and cat bonds.

I have a good statistical background and master-level knowledge of financial engineering. I am looking to learn more technical/practical details on the pricing side of these derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find little beyond the standard actuarial literature on the underlying contracts, which are really just XL covers. Since these contracts are written in non-liquid markets risk neutral or market consistent pricing is not highly developed or doesn't even make a lot of sense. In any way most of the information is proprietary and non-public. The only place I know of where you can find public analysis is [Morton Lane's site](http://www.lanefinancialllc.com). You can register for free and have a look at their publications.

Comment: Is Antal's book of any value? http://www.actuaries.ch/fr/downloads/aid!b4ae4834-66cd-464b-bd27-1497194efc96/id!96/Reinsurance_Script2009_v2.pdf (I haven't read it).

Comment: Yes, it is. But of course these are lecture notes on the basic concepts, so do not expect market colour or ILS specifics.